# Openlayers remove previously drawn polygon on starting to draw next one

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, vector, features

Objective:

At any point of time there SHOULD only be zero/one polygon(s) on a vector layer with a polygon control. I need the previous polygon to be removed as soon as user starts drawing the first vertex of the next polygon.

Code:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapDiv, options);
var tempLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Temp Layer");
map.addLayer(tempLayer);

var polyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(tempLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);

polyControl.events.register('featureadded', ' ', removeExistingPolygon);

function removeExistingPolygon(feature) //Assuming event listener gets a feature object
//Written mainly with featureadded in mind
{
  if(feature.layer.features.length > 1){
    feature.layer.removeFeatures(feature.layer.features[0]);
  }
}

tempLayer.events.register(<event_name>, ' ', <prev_polygon_removal_function>);
```

Question:

What event_name and function should I use to attain the objective? I have tried 'sketchstarted' on tempLayer but it gets triggered even before user starts to draw a polygon. 'vertexmodified' doesn't seem to work at all.

Objective is partially satisfied when using featureadded with polyControl but in that case the first polygon remains visible till the second one is completed.

Any pointers on how to proceed are most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You kind of have catch-22 or at minimum not detailed enough requirements.  Specifically - do you want to remove the 1st feature as SOON as the user starts drawing a new feature? Or when they're done?  Because you could end up blowing out your 1st feature and user cancels out of drawing 2nd feature and then you have nothing.

You have 2 additional things you can register:

1) Register to listen for the `Control`'s `activate` event.  When the drawing tool is activated, just blow out any features in the layer.
1a) And by the way, it's better to just say `layer.removeAllFeatures()` instead of the way you have it.

2) Register to listen for the `Layer`'s `beforefeatureadded` event and work your logic in there.  http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.events

Comment: I want to remove the 1st feature as SOON as the user starts drawing a new feature.

Comment: And one thing I missed, the draw control is always active. So can't use first solution. Regarding 1a) my existing code removes the feature AFTER the second one is done., don't you think `removeAllFeatures()` would remove them both in that case? As for 2) `beforefeatureadded` kicks in only just before `featureadded` and not when I place/draw the first vertex of the second polygon.

Comment: Ok, then you have to go lower at the `Handler` events.  Look at the `Point` and `Polygon` events http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Point-js.html and perhaps `create` in `Point` and `point` in `Polygon` are what you're looking for.  There you can check "ok, are there other shapes?  Delete them" and in `Polygon` you'll have to check "is this 1st point? -delete old on.  has `done` fired yet? no, then user is just drawing stuff"

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. `point` in `Polygon Handler` did the trick. And I used `create` for `RegularPolygon Handler`.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is built with the excellent help from @Vadim. Read through his answer and ensuing comments for a detailed explanation**

Another helpful link about handler callbacks: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37741/10620

Solution:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapDiv, options);
var tempLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Temp Layer");
map.addLayer(tempLayer);

var polyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(tempLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);

polyControl.handler.callbacks.point = function(data) {
    if(tempLayer.features.length > 0)
    {
        tempLayer.removeAllFeatures();
    }
}

var regPolyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(tempLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon);

regPolyControl.handler.callbacks.create = function(data) {
    if(tempLayer.features.length > 0)
    {
        tempLayer.removeAllFeatures();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you got to the bottom of this, but I'm not really sure why you gave yourself the answer? hmmm.

Comment: The direct answer to my question is the one above. Myself being a lazy bum, usually look for the direct answers to questions before going into the details. Likewise this will help people who are searching for a quick answer. If they do want to know in detail, they can always refer to your helpful answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, agree with @Vadim: not very gentleman-like to just regurgitate the answer Vadim gave you, and then award yourself the answer. At least give the man some credit for helping you.

Comment: Good that you shared the final code, but awarding yourself the correct answer is bad form.

Answer (score 0):

"polyControl.handler.callbacks.point = function(data) {
    if(tempLayer.features.length > 0)
    {
        tempLayer.removeAllFeatures();
    }
}"      No 'callbacks' properties

Comment: Please consider adding more details to the answer which provide context to this code. As it stands, it is not not clear what this code does, or how it should be used.